# Where can I find a NServiceBus 4.1 message during an SLR retry?

Tags: nservicebus4

We are currently implementing a new system. It now happens, that the content of my message is wrong and gets rejected by the connecting system (we transfer data over a REST service). I can edit my message as soon as it is in the error queue and re-queue it. But while NServiceBus is trying to re-send it (which will of course fail every time), I can't seem to find the message to correct it for the next time around. Any idea where the message is "parked" during SLR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message gets moved to our timeout storage, which is by default RavenDB.

Comment: Hi Udi, I was able to find a timeout collection in the RavenDB, but it contained only meta data, including the last caught exception. But I couldn't locate the actual message data.

Comment: The message data is stored in binary format in the "state" property: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.Core/Timeout/Core/TimeoutData.cs#L29